# EmberJS: how to show a background-image while the JS content is being downloaded?

Tags: ember.js

Loading all the JS and CSS files can take a bit of time on a slow connection (e.g. mobile). So I was hoping to show a "loading…" image while it is happening. To be clear: the problem is not so much the initialisation of the Ember app itself, but the time it takes to download the content.

Is there a way to do this? It is not an Ember only issue, but I guess Ember developers may have been confronted to this as well?

I set a background-color and background-image to the `<html>` tag. When the app loads, I do see the background-color for a little while (before it gets covered by the `<body>` content), but not the background-image.

Thanks,

PJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image may be taking time to load. The data may have finished loading before the image shows up.

For showing a loading spinner specifically for data loading, look into the recent [async router](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945) changes. The beforeModel and afterModel hooks on the route are perfect for doing this.

```
beforeModel: function() {
  // show spinner
}

afterModel: function() {
  // hide spinner
}
```

Edit: Embedding the image with [data-uri](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) works.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that won't help in my case - I need to show the image before the ember javascript file itself is downloaded (so before the app is created). These new hooks are really helpful, but only once your app is initialised.

Comment: Try embedding the image with [data-uri](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/), possibly within the main html itself with an inline style tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about this (data-uri) and it's exactly what I needed.